# nginx configuration for angular and nest.js app deploy

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx, azure-webapps

I am trying to deploy my angular & nest.js app. I successfully created an image from Dockerfile, and uploaded it to DockerHub. I have a Web App on Azure, which connects to the DockerHub and uses that image. When I try to access the deployed app, I can't get rid of the Nginx welcome page.
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12

# Install SSH
RUN apt update && apt install -y openssh-server nginx gettext-base

# Copy the sshd_config file to the /etc/ssh/ directory
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/

# Open port 2222 for SSH access
EXPOSE 80 2222 3333

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY supervisor/supervisord_static /usr/local/bin/supervisord
COPY supervisor/supervisor.conf ./

# Copy code to the container
COPY . .
# Install NPM modules and build app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build:prod:api && npm run build:prod:ui

COPY ./nginx-gzip.conf /etc/nginx/gzip.conf
COPY ./nginx.conf.template /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template

## Remove default nginx index page
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY apps/portal/ /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 2222 80 4200 3333

CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "supervisor.conf"]
```

and the nginx.conf.template:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
    server {
        listen 80;
        #root  /usr/src/app/dist/apps/portal;
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
        location /config {
          proxy_pass      127.0.0.1:3333/config;
        }
        location /api {
          proxy_pass      127.0.0.1:3333/api;
        }
        location /swagger {
          proxy_pass      127.0.0.1:3333/swagger;
        }
    }

    # Compression
    include /etc/nginx/gzip.conf;
}
```

and my nginx-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -eu

envsubst 'http://localhost:4200/api' < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

exec "$@"
```

So this page appears no matter what I do or change in my code. What am I doing wrong?
[nginx-welcome-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGgOS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, it says that the file does not exist (I checked and conf.d folder it's actually empty). Still going to investingate. Thanks for your answer!